# How can I save csv separately based on it's entry column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv, export-to-csv

I am trying to save csv files after extracting dataframe from MONGODB.

When I create dataframe it is generating each dataframe based on its date columns.

Further more dataframe has a column `id` which has 31 different id number.

I want to save my csv separetly including id number in csv name.

I was saving my dataframe in this way before by using pandas:

```
data = pd.DataFrame(energy_data)


for each_id in id_list:
    item = int(each_id)
    data.to_csv(os.path.join(dir, f'test_id_{item}.csv'), sep=',' )
                
# data is a dataframe I get it from MongoDB.
```

My dataframe looks like below(which shows 31 separate dataframe while I print):

```
datetimeAt            id.      total
2022-01-01 23:00:00   10121     1088030

.................
.................

datetimeAt            id.      total
2022-01-09 21:00:00   10023     1077030

................
................

datetimeAt            id.      total
2022-01-16 20:00:00   10024     1058030

..............
.................

datetimeAt            id.      total
2022-01-15 15:00:00   10012     108030
...................
```

When I run my code, I was able to get 31 csv files but each csv contains same data informatin i.e. first dataframe when I print from my extraction function.

So I want to save my csv based on id number as below with information corresponding to it's id number.

```
test_id-10121.csv
test_id-10023.csv
test_id-10024.csv
test_id-10012.csv
.................
```

Can I get some help?

Thank you

Comment: Because you use `data.to_csv()` where `data` is the complete dataset. If you want a subset only, then create a subset and save that only. I don't think it is `item` nor `each_id` and it's unclear what data you want to have in each individual file.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, can I get little bit help to create subset...?

Comment: You are using `to_csv` on the same `data` instance all the way through the loop. If you want to separate based on `id` you can either [filter](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html) with something like `data[data["id"] == each_id]` or with the [`groupby` method](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html).

Comment: Probably something like `subset = data[data["id"] == item]` or `subset = data[data["id"] == each_id]`

Comment: See also: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/getting_started/intro_tutorials/03_subset_data.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pandas is great at selecting only relevant informations. You have simply to do:

```
for each_id in id_list:
    item = int(each_id)
    data[data[id] == item].to_csv(os.path.join(dir, f'test_id_{item}.csv'), sep=',' )
```

It could be:

```
...
    data[data[id] == each_id].to_csv(os.path.join(dir, f'test_id_{item}.csv'), sep=',' )
```

if the `id` column was not numeric...

---

But if you have a large dataframe and a rather high number of id values, it would not be efficient because you will repeat the extraction process for each id value. The Pandas way is to use `grouby`:

```
for item, df_item in df.groupby('id'):
    df_item.to_csv(os.path.join(dir, f'test_id_{item}.csv'), sep=',' )
```

Comment: @drmeltan: Using groupby is probably better. Please see my edit.

Comment: dg is df right? it says 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'group_by'. I suppose  it must be groupby.

Comment: @drmeltan Oops, 2 typos in one single line! Time for me to have a coffee...

Answer (score 1):

For each id you need to split out a set of data from the main dataframe and save that separately.

To do that you can use something like this.

```py
for each_id in id_list:
    item = int(each_id)
    data_for_id = data[data['id.'] == item]
    data_for_id.to_csv(os.path.join(dir, f'test_id_{item}.csv'), sep=',' )
```

Comment: Thanks Norie, Let me try mentioned idea in my code.